# Hybrid Fat/Snow Bike

Tags: snow

I've seen some bikes with a pugsley or similar fork and 3"+ tires on a hard tail mtb frame.

-Has anyone done this them selves? 
-Do you really notice any flotation with only one fat tire and one regular? (2.3" is the max my rear triangle will accept)

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a Fat-Front setup.

Cornering on soft surfaces should be improved, as well as shock absorption if you run low pressure, but drive would only improve in the case where the fat front tyre can compact snow enough for the regular rear tyre to dig in less than it would on a standard MTB.

Comment: I haven't done this myself (I already own a fatbike) but I do have a spare rigid fat fork. Current problems which stop me making use of this are the unavailability of low-end 135mm front hubs and the unavailability of storage space at my house, due to N+1.

Comment: Well it depends on the fork for that option - for example, Salsa Enabler uses a rear hub in the front.

Comment: Yep, My fork is an On One Fatty steel fork, so I need a hub with front disc spacing, or a rear hub with spacers.

Comment: Still, N+1 vs storage space ;-)